# Display error in spinboxes (numericupdown)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

when using windows forms spinboxes, I have some display problems. On some computers, everything works fine, but on some computers, they have a black border and look like this:
[image: Error display spinbox]

Does anybody have an idea what the error could be?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: some screenshots might help other people to help you

Comment: Do other applications also look like that on the other computers?  Perhaps the host OS is styling elements differently?

Comment: please clarify your complete scenario, some computers mean?

Comment: All computers have the same OS?

Comment: Yes, sorry, not enough information but the problem is, on my computer everything works fine. Problems are on older machines, Windows XP is used and .NET 2.0. And the problem is not in comboboxes but in spinboxes (numericupdown). I think there is a redraw problem.

Comment: I cannot see the same error in other applications but unfortunately, there are no installed using spinboxes, too.

Comment: Do the problematic machines have the correct display drivers installed and not just the generic one?